# Looping through all item except itself

Tags: python

I am trying to find the item in a list with highest number of occurrence.

For this, I am trying to compare every item in list with all other items in list and increasing count's value by 1 each time a match is found.

```
def findInt(array):
    count = []
    count = [1 for i in range(0,len(array))]        
    for i,item in enumerate(array):
        if (array[i] == array[i:]):  #How can I compare it with all items except itself?
            count[i]+=1

    return max(count), count.index(max(count))


findInt(array=[1,2,3])
```

My question is "how do I compare the item with all other items except itself"?

Comment: You'd need to loop again, making your approach O(n*2) and thus not very good. But I don't understand why you're trying to do it this way; just increment `count[i]` for each item and be done with it? The `if` is superfluous.

Comment: That's an awfully convoluted way to count occurrences. Use `collections.Counter` to do your dirty work.

Comment: @zwer This is considering if you can't use built-in functions like counter to do the job.

Comment: `enumerate`, `range`, `len` and `max` are also built-in functions, not much different than `collections.Counter` (which is also not a function but a type, but lets not discuss semantics)

Comment: Well, if the problem statement is "find item with maximum occurrence in an array", you wouldn't just use a built-in method, would you?

Comment: Yes I would. That's why built-ins exist - so you don't have to reinvent the wheel and go through the whole ordeal over and over again.

Comment: Okay, you probably wouldn't do that in an interview.

Comment: Actually, I would - and since I've interviewed quite a few candidates I'd readily discard anyone trying to reinvent the wheel. Sure, if the question is 'design an algorithm to find the highest occurrence of a element in a list' I would expect people to know how to do it, but if the question is presented as yours I would *expect* candidates to use built-ins. But I digress, comments here are not for chat...

Answer (score 2):

use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which has a [most_common](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) function.

```
import collections
def findInt(array):
    c = collections.Counter(array)
    return c.most_common(1)
```

**DEMO**

```
>>> import collections
>>> array=[1,2,3,1,2,3,2]
>>> c = collections.Counter(array)
>>> c.most_common(1)
[(2, 3)]
```

*DOC*

> **class collections.Counter([iterable-or-mapping])**
>   A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.
>
> **most_common([n])**
>   Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common() returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily:

Comment: Edit: `collections.Counter()` doesn't work for me, because this is built-in method and that defeats the purpose of solving the problem in first place.

Comment: @ramailosathi Sorry, I didn't get your point. Is there any reason not using the perfect built-in method?

Comment: My bad,the question should be "design an algorithm to find the highest occurrence of a element in a list"

Comment: Honestly speaking, does this do any good to your project? I recommend you to spend more time on something more critical to your project or so.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there exist many better ways of solving this problem, for instance as indicated in @zwer's comment to your question, here's how I would solve exactly what you're asking:

```
# O(n ** 2)
def find_int(array):
    n = len(array)
    count = [1 for i in range(n)]

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i == j: continue

            if array[i] == array[j]:
                count[i] += 1

    return max(count), count.index(max(count))

# Worse than O(n ** 2)
def find_int_using_slice(array):
    n = len(array)
    count = [1 for i in range(n)]

    for i in range(n):
        for a_j in array[0:i] + array[i+1:]:
            if array[i] == a_j:
                count[i] += 1

    return max(count), count.index(max(count))

print(find_int_using_slice([1,2,3,1,2,3,2]))
```

We're using a nested for-loop here and using `continue` to skip the iteration when the two indexes are the same.

Unless specifically for the purpose of learning, please consider using built-ins for common tasks this, as they are well implemented, tested, optimised, etc.

There are many potential solutions, but here are the two I'd recommend, depending on your application's requirements: 1) sort and count in a single pass from left to right: O(n * log(n)) and losing the original ordering, or 2) use a dictionary to maintain the counts, requiring only a single pass from left to right: O(n) but using more memory. Of course the better decision would be to use in-built methods which are highly optimised, but that's your call

Comment: Awesome, but is there any way I can use slicing for this purpose?

Comment: @ramailosathi - why are you insisting on doing this in a most inefficient way imaginable?!

Comment: Ehh... I'll add an example which uses slicing, but I hope you can think about it and realise why it's considerably inefficient

Comment: @zwer what is the efficient way without using collections.counter() or anything similar then?

Comment: I'd probably use a sort and a single pass through to compare

Comment: I will do that. Thanks @BilalAkil

Comment: There are many potential solutions, but here are the two I'd recommend, depending on your application's requirements: 1) sort and count in a single pass from left to right: O(n * log(n)) and losing the original ordering, or 2) use a dictionary to maintain the counts, requiring only a single pass from left to right: O(n) but using more memory.

Of course the better decision would be to use in-built methods which are highly optimised, but that's your call

Comment: You should add that to your answer :) +1.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer to reflect OP not wanting to use `collections.Counter`

Using `setdefault` to prime the counter for first occurrences, then increment the counter. Then you can use `max` with a key to find the most common item.

```
def most_common(ar):
    y = {}

    for item in ar:
        y.setdefault(item, 0)
        y[item] += 1

    return max(y.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

array = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]
most_common(array)

(1, 5)  # (Most common item, occurrences of item)
```

Comment: This looks like O(n), is it? Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Also why not just `return y.items()`? It will return item and occurrence count.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's 0(n) as you'll have to loop through every n items in the array you pass. As for returning y.items, you could do that if you want all items. I was assuming you only want the single item that occurs the most often.

Comment: I meant `return max(y.items())`. Why that lambda expression?

Comment: Ahh yes, because `y.items()` returns tuples, I used the lambda to make sure to get the `max` based off of the occurrence count (position 1 of the tuple). Otherwise the output of `max` will be relative to the key, which in this case is the item, not the item count.

Answer (score 0):

```
def findInt(array):
count = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    count.append(array.count(array[i]))

return max(count), count.index(max(count))
```

print(findInt(array=[1,2,3,1,2,3,2]))

Answer (score 0):

Fine, I'll bite - given that memory is cheap, hashing is preferred over looping. I'd reckon one of the most performant ways would be to use a temporary registry:

```
def findInt(array):
    occurrences = dict.fromkeys(array, 0)
    for element in array:
        occurrences[element] += 1
    items = occurrences.values()
    max_occurences = max(items)
    return occurrences.keys()[items.index(max_occurences)], max_occurences
```

Returns a tuple of the element that occurs the most, and the number of times it occurs.

Actually, let's optimize it even more - here's a pure O(N) solution with no extra list building and searching:

```
def findInt(array):
    occurrences = dict.fromkeys(array, 0)
    candidate = array[0]
    occurs = 0
    for element in array:
        value = occurrences[element] + 1
        occurrences[element] = value
        if value > occurs:
            candidate = element
            occurs = value
    return candidate, occurs
```

Comment: Sorry for not phrasing the question properly, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` is ideal for counting frequencies of items in an iterable.  Alternatively, you can loop once with a `defaultdict`.

```
import operator as op
import collections as ct

def findInt(array):
    dd = ct.defaultdict(int)
    for item in array:
        dd[item] += 1
    return dd

# Frequencies
array = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]
freq = findInt(array)
freq
# Out: defaultdict(int, {1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 2})

# Maximum key-value pair  (2 options)
{k:v for k,v in freq.items() if k == max(freq, key=lambda x: freq[x])}
# Out: {1: 5}
max({k:v for k,v in freq.items()}.items(), key=op.itemgetter(-1))
# Out: (1: 5)
```